# Alcance de funcion

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Estoy haciendo un CRUD con javascript y firebase y me encontre con el siguiente problema....

La funcion:

> onGetTasks(callback)

trae la informacion de la collection tasks de firebase y la muestra en la pagina y ademas añade a la lista de tareas una nueva tarea en cuanto es insertada .

Mi problema esta en que si saco mi funcion

> **makeListenerBtnDelete()**

de dentro de la funcion *onGetTasks()* (donde donde la funcion se ejecuta multiples veces) no tengo el resultado esperado... ya sea al final del on '**DOMContentLoaded**' que fuera en mi archivo js ejecutándola por separado... pero si hago
un **document.querySelectorAll('.task-delete')** desde el navegador si selecciona todos los nodos. Este es el codigo. Me gustaria saber porque sucede esto. Saludos

```js
const onGetTasks = (callback) => db.collection('tasks').onSnapshot(callback)

const makeListenerBtnDelete = () =>{
      //selecciono los botones
     const btnDelete = document.querySelectorAll(".task-delete");
      //annado los event listeners
     btnDelete.forEach((btn) => {
       btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
         console.log("click");
       });
     });
}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () =>{
    const tasksContainer = document.getElementById("task-container");
    
    await onGetTasks((querySnapshot) =>{
        tasksContainer.innerHTML += ``
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const { title, description } = doc.data();
          tasksContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="card card-body mt-2 border-primary">
                <h5>${title}</h5>
                <p>${description}</p>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                    <button class="task-delete btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
        });
       makeListenerBtnDelete()        
    })
    
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" id="task-container">
  <!- Aqui irian las card ejemplo -->
   <div class="card card-body mt-2 border-primary">
                <h5>1984</h5>
                <p>Una distopia</p>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                    <button class="task-delete btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="card card-body mt-2 border-primary">
                <h5>La maquina del tiempo</h5>
                <p>clasico de ciencia ficcion, el hombre...</p>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                    <button class="task-delete btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando agregas elementos dinámicamente tienes dos opciones:

1. Llamar la función como lo estás haciendo ahora, justo después de cargar los nuevos elementos
2. Delegar el evento, asignándolo al documento y analizando dónde se hizo clic

Asignar el evento cuando se carga el DOM no funciona, porque se aplica solo a los elementos que ya existen y no es posible asignarlos a los que vas agregando.

En este ejemplo, inicias con un elemento y se van agregando más al hacer clic en el botón *Cargar*. El evento *onclick* está asignado al documento y ahí es donde se analiza dónde se disparó para ejecutar las instrucciones correspondientes al botón.

```js
const data = [
  { "title":"1984", "description": "Una distopia..."},
  { "title":"La Máquina del tiempo", "description": "Clásico de ciencia ficción..."},
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
    const tasksContainer = document.querySelector("#task-container");
    const cargar = document.querySelector('#cargar');
    cargar.addEventListener('click', function() {
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const {title, description} = doc;
            tasksContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="card card-body mt-2 border-primary">
                <h5>${title}</h5>
                <p>${description}</p>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                    <button class="task-delete btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          `;
        });
    });
    // Se asigna evento onclick al documento
    // El evento se recibe como parámetro (e)
    document.addEventListener('click', e => {
        // e.target es el elemento que disparó el evento
        // Si la clase corresponde al botón
        if(e.target.classList.contains('task-delete')) {
            // Obtener padre
            const parent = e.target.closest('.card');
            // Obtener título
            const title = parent.querySelector('h5');
            console.log(title.innerText);
            // Borrar tarjeta
            tasksContainer.removeChild(parent);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" id="task-container">
          <div class="card card-body mt-2 border-primary">
                <h5>Volver al Futuro</h5>
                <p>Un elemento existente desde inicio</p>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                    <button class="task-delete btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
<button id="cargar">Cargar datos</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! No habia utilizado el DOMContentLoaded... que en mi caso lo encuentro mas incomodo trabajar con el por esta y otras cosas que me voy encontrando

Comment: En tu caso, no era problema del momento en que defines la función, sino que solo aplicaba a los elementos existentes y no a los agregados dinámicamente.